# How to implement UrbanAirship in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, urbanairship.com

I have Xamarin.Form project and I want to implement UrbanAirship in it so I can get notification in user device. I have followed this [document](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/xamarin/).

> 1- Install NUGET in iOS/Droid project: PM> Install-Package
>   UrbanAirship
>
> 2- Install NUGET in Portable project: PM> Install-Package
>   UrbanAirship.Portable
>
> 3- Add AirshipConfig.plist file according to given in document
>
> 4- Set `UAirship.TakeOff();` and
>   `UAirship.Push.UserPushNotificationsEnabled = true;` in AppDelegate
>
> 5- Add/Remove Tags wherever required in Portal project.
>
> 6- Create a library(service) in portal project and iOS project to
>   manage calls between Portable and iOS project. It contains method like
>   `SetNamedUser`, `TrackScreen`, `RemoveNamedUser`

I have done with this. Do I need to implement push notification separately now? Or is it enough for this?

Please suggest, I am new in this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should create your app on the Urban Airship to get your app's `AppKey` and `AppSecret` which is required in the AirshipConfig.plist.

**For iOS:**

We need to register the APNS certifications on Apple's developer center. See the [APNS Setup documentation](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/push-providers/apns/) for more details.

**For Android:**

I found this sdk just uses FCM to send the notification. So you also need to follow the setup on FCM: https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/push-providers/fcm/